# Совместимость интерфейсов Closeable и AutoCloseable

Tags: java

В Java 1.5 был введен интерфейс `Closeable` с одним методом `close()`. В Java 1.7 был добавлен оператор `try-with-resources`, и для этого был введен интерфейс `AutoCloseable`, который был сделан родительским интерфейсом `Closeable`.

Как я понимаю, это было сделано для того, чтобы все классы, которые реализовывали интерфейс `Closeable`, автоматически можно было использовать в операторе `try-with-resources`. Но тогда непонятен вообще смысл ввода этого интерфейса. Почему бы тогда не сделать, чтобы этот оператор работал сразу с существующим интерфейсом `Closeable`, а не новым `AutoCloseable`?

Или это было сделано только для того, чтобы метод `close()` мог бросать любые исключения, а не только наследники от `IOException`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В методе `close` интерфейса `Closeable` есть два ограничения, которые хотели ослабить при вводе конструкции try-with-resources:

1. Проброс только `IOException`, что не подходит для всех. Например, для [java.sql.Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()).
2. Требование идемпотентности. В `AutoCloseable` его нет, хотя это и "[крайне рекомендуется](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close())".

Comment: Спасибо. Про требования идемпотентности для `Closeable.close()` даже не знал